# Error with orphanRemobval with a @OneToMany column

Tags: java, kotlin, spring-data-jpa

I'm currently runnning a little app with SpringBoot and JPA.
I have the following file with all the entities :

```
@Entity
class User(
    @Id var username: String,
    var password: String,
    @OneToOne(cascade = [CascadeType.ALL]) 
    var basket : ShoppingCart = ShoppingCart()
)

@Entity
class Product(
    @Id var name: String,
    var quantity : Int = 0,
    var price: Double = 0.0
)

@Entity
class CartItem(
    @Id @GeneratedValue var id : UUID? = null,
    @ManyToOne var product : Product,
    var quantity : Int = 0
)

@Entity
class ShoppingCart(
    @Id @GeneratedValue var id : UUID? = null,
    @OneToMany(cascade=[CascadeType.REMOVE], orphanRemoval = true) 
    var cartItems: MutableSet<CartItem> = mutableSetOf()
)
```

It works all fine, but whenever I want to delete a CartItem (belonging to a ShoppingCart), I have an error of foreign key violation.
It's because the foreig key pointing on the cart_item.id of the generated shopping_cart_cart_items has ON DELETE RESTRICT.
I'd like this generated table to have ON DELETE CASCADE instead of ON DELETE RESTRICT.

Do you know where could be my problem ?

Many thanks !